# Wild shape monster save DC.

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, wild-shape

When you are wild shaping into a monster do you use your own or the monsters hit dice for the sake of determining the DC for the abilities of that creature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [wild shape](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/druid.htm#wildShape) is based on [alternate form](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#alternateForm) and alternate form makes no mention of *changing* or *recomputing* a creature's Hit Dice, the creature's Hit Dice are unchanged. That means if a creature were to employ wild shape to assume the form of a creature with a special ability having a saving throw (like an extraordinary attack), that saving throw, if normally based on the *new* creature's Hit Dice, would instead be based on the *original* creature's Hit Dice.

For example, a level 20 druid that uses wild shape to assume the form of a [tendriculos](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/tendriculos.htm) gains the creature's extraordinary attack swallow whole/paralysis. A typical tendriculos requires its foes to make a Fortitude saving throw (DC 22) against its paralytic digestive juices, but the druid 20 in the form of a tendriculos increases the Fortitude saving throw DC to 26 (that is, 10 + 10 (half of 20 druid Hit Dice) + 6 (the modifier of the tendriculos's Con 22)).

(The reverse is also true: a level 20 druid that employs wild shape to take the form of a [cat](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/cat.htm) doesn't suddenly become vulnerable to the spell [*sleep*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/sleep.htm) despite having assumed the form of a ½HD creature.)

Note that typically wild shape doesn't grant spell-like and supernatural abilities and only grants extraordinary special *attacks* of the new form. Most abilities that are gained (like movement modes and natural attacks) don't usually require saving throws in the first place.